# Docker and playwright

Tags: python, docker

I need to install playwright inside of docker. This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.9

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /fastanalytics

COPY /requirements.txt /fastanalytics/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /fastanalytics/requirements.txt

RUN playwright install
RUN playwright install-deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

But when I am installing I got the below error. I tried installing everything in the error message but it didn't help.

```
E: Package 'ttf-ubuntu-font-family' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libenchant1c2a
E: Unable to locate package libicu66
E: Package 'libjpeg-turbo8' has no installation candidate
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft released a python docker image for Playwright

Dockerfile

```
# Build Environment: Playwright
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.21.0-focal

# Add python script to Docker
COPY index.py /

# Run Python script
CMD [ "python", "index.py" ]
```

Check [Playwright - Docker docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker) for the latest playwright version.

Answer (score 5):

Based on their docs (https://playwright.dev/python/docs/cli#install-system-dependencies), it looks like they only officially support Ubuntu systems whereas the `python:3.9` is based off of Debian. Try using Ubuntu as your base image and install python on it:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3.9

...
```

Answer (score 2):

There has been a fix to this and in order to get this working properly you just have to install the actual chromium binary files to a specific directory during install and then specify that directory as a Environment variable.

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.10.7

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/app/ms-playwright
# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
#..... whatever else you need 
RUN pip install playwright
# install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils
RUN PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/app/ms-playwright python -m playwright install --with-deps chromium
```

If it errors out try to throw a

```
RUN sudo apt-get clean
RUN sudo apt-get update
```

before it

Comment: this solved it for me. move the install folder to a location other then app, cos I copy over the dir and playwright gets deleted then.

Answer (score 1):

`RUN apt-get update && playwright install-deps`

While I have not used playwright, this seems to be a Docker issue. Playwright seems to be using `apt-get` to install the dependencies. In that case, you need to ensure `apt-get update` is run before `playwright install-deps`. While you can use two separate `RUN` statements to accomplish this, it is not advisable since`apt-get update` may not be run because of Docker's caching capabilities.

Comment: thatnks for answering, i tried, didnt help, the same errors

```FROM python:3.9

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /fastanalytics

COPY /requirements.txt /fastanalytics/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /fastanalytics/requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && playwright install-deps
RUN apt-get update && playwright install



COPY . /fastanalytics```