# Dockerfile in Python for Playwright Chromium, installing error

Tags: python, django, docker, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to add playwright with chromium to a django project. I modify my docker to include the installation of playwright with chromium.
When i use `docker-compose up --build` and then execute the function that use playwright i get the following error:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Executable doesn't exist at /usr/bin/chromium-1067/chrome-linux/chrome

╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright was just installed or updated.       ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers: ║
║                                                            ║
║     playwright install                                     ║
║                                                            ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I checked the files inside my docker and in the path `/usr/bin/` i found `chromium-1071` installed. I dont know how playwright is checking for the specific path `chromium-1067` and i also dont know why it installed `chromium-1071`.
I need help with the correct implementation of playwright in my django project.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.9
ARG ENVIRONMENT=default
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor curl wget gnupg unzip 


RUN pip install playwright

ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/usr/bin

RUN playwright install-deps chromium

RUN playwright install chromium


COPY start-container.sh /usr/local/bin/start-container.sh
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container.sh

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install "setuptools<58.0.0"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5555

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container.sh"]
```

Also i use a docker-compose.yml, i didnt modified it.

Comment: Playwright requires you to run on a Ubuntu based image. You can either use the official Playwright image or use Ubuntu and install Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042138/docker-and-playwright/71051968

Comment: Try adding your env var for the Playwright path to the system path: PATH=$PATH:PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering this error because the Playwright package you installed is looking for Chromium version 1067 but you have Chromium version 1071 installed in your Docker environment.

One possible reason for this mismatch could be that you are installing Playwright and Chromium separately in your Dockerfile, and the versions are not compatible with each other.

One approach to address this issue is to allow Playwright to handle the browser installation itself. When you install Playwright, it also installs the compatible browser binaries automatically, so you might not need to use `playwright install-deps chromium` and `playwright install chromium` separately.

try to update your Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.9

ARG ENVIRONMENT=default
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor curl wget gnupg unzip 

# You should install the dependencies required to run the browsers.
# There's no need to install chromium separately
RUN apt-get install -y libnss3 libasound2 libgbm-dev

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install "setuptools<58.0.0"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install playwright and then its dependencies (the browsers)
RUN pip install playwright
RUN playwright install

COPY start-container.sh /usr/local/bin/start-container.sh
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container.sh

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5555

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container.sh"]
```

This way, Playwright will install a compatible version of Chromium that it can use.

Remember, each time you upgrade Playwright, make sure to re-run `playwright install` so that compatible versions of the browsers get installed. You may need to do this manually, or better yet, use a script that does this as part of your build process.

Comment: `playwright install` did it for me.