# How do I deploy a Python Flask App that uses Playwright on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-run, playwright

I'm trying to deploy a Python Flask App that uses Playwright on Google Cloud Run with a docker image. I've read from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72136540/12323890) that you'd need to use the Playwright Python images provided by Microsoft. However whenever I used and deploy the web app (using "Deploy to Cloud Run"), it just shows a blank page with a text `Services unavailable`.

I've read some Docker documentation for Playwright and was under the impression that you don't need to install any Playwright (pip install or the browsers) if you use this image on Docker. So I try to install with playwright==1.40.2 on requirements.txt and without, however the result is the same as above.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.40.0-jammy

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
flask==2.3.2
Flask-Session==0.5.0
Werkzeug==2.3.4
Flask-WTF==1.2.1
WTForms==3.1.1
textfsm==1.1.2
xlwt==1.3.0
netaddr==0.9.0
pandas==2.1.1
xlrd==2.0.1
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
python-magic
playwright==1.40.0
gunicorn
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I tried using regular `FROM python:3` as my docker image, and the web app was deployed just fine, albeit returning an error when I try to run the web scraping function.

Comment: Check the Cloud Run logs for more details. Add those to your post.

Comment: @AB3, Can you able to run this on your local machine successfully? I was able to succesfully deploy following [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service#writing) with your dockerfile and requirement.txt. Can you share what do you have in your [app.py](http://app.py) along with error logs

Comment: @AB3 Have you managed to check the above comments? Let us know if you are still facing issue, so that we can solve it further.